# Can anyone suggest a way of coding captureing keystrokes without waiting for keys to be pressed?

Tags: c, turbo-c

I'm coding a snake game in C and my compiler is turbo C.
I've got a problem with moving the snake. I need a function or a way of coding so that I can move my snake without the keyboard waiting for a key to be pressed. but if a key is pressed some specific actions are to be done. I used the structure below but it doesn't work as I explained above:

```
while (gameStatus == CONTINUE)
{
   if(kbhit)
   {
      char c = getch();
      .....
   }
   .....
}
```

can anyone help?

Comment: kbhit is a function.  When you write `if(kbhit)` you are testing if the function exists.  Instead call the function by writing `if(kbhit())`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: really really thanks. It got to be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kbhit is a function. When you write if(kbhit) you are testing if the function exists. Instead call the function by writing if(kbhit()).

Answer (score 0):

```
while (gameStatus == CONTINUE)
{
    if (kbhit())
    {
         char c = '\0';

         /*a keystroke return 0*/
         if ((c=getch())!=0) 
         {
            c=getch(); /*then you capture the actual directional key*/

            ......conditionals 
         }
         //else if not was a directional, you Can Pause or Something  
     .....
    }
.....
}
```